# AJAX GET Call Will work on the first call but not after other clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call in my javascript that returns and loads a partial view into a div. This function used to work but then all the sudden it stopped. I do not think I changed any code or anything that would cause issue but obviously something is going on. The Ajax call will work on the first time when you click on the button in which it is called but never again until you reload the page. I have tried adding more parameters and moving the javascript around but it still did not work. Is there any reason why this could happen?

I have tried moving the javascript out of the onOpen event and the same thing still happens. I have also put an alert call to make sure it is getting to the success call and the alert is called. I have also installed fiddler to check the call and the call is never made except on the first click of the button. This is a very frustrating error and all help is much appreciated.

Here is my Javascript:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#assets-button").on("click", function ()
            {
                $('#assets-container').bPopup(
                {
                    modal: true,
                    onOpen: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '@Url.Action("EmployeeAssets", "Employee",new { id = Model.ID, empNo = Model.EmployeeNumber, username = Model.UserName })',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#assets-container').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    onClose: function () {
                        var f = $('#assets-container').children('form');
                        var serializedForm = f.serialize();
                        var action = '@Url.Action("EmployeeAssets","Employee",new {empNo = Model.EmployeeNumber})';
                        $.post(action, serializedForm);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here is the action that I am trying to call:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EmployeeAssets(int id, int empNo, string username = null)
{
    var assets =  _employeeDb.EmployeeAssets.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmpNo == empNo);
    if (assets == null)
    {
        var firstOrDefault = _employeeDb.EmployeeMasters.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeNumber == empNo);
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
        {
            username = firstOrDefault.UserName;
        }
        var newasset = new EmployeeAsset()
        {
            EmpNo = empNo,
            UserName = username

        };
        _employeeDb.EmployeeAssets.Add(newasset);
        _employeeDb.SaveChanges();
        assets = newasset;
    }
    return PartialView(assets);
}
```

Comment: "it stopped [working]" - what does this mean? If you see `alert` in `success` handler - the code reaches there. What is `data` in that case? Obviously, you have another `EmployeeAssets` action marked with `[HttpPost]` and without `id` parameter, correct?

Comment: You haven't posted you html but is `#assets-button` a child element of `#assets-container`? (in which case your replacing the original `#assets-button` with a new `#assets-button`)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the cache property of the settings object you are passing to the AJAX call.  According to the [jQuery documentation for .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the default for cache is set to true, so I wonder whether your browser is accessing a cached copy of the result after the first request. Looks like you could also set the dataType, and that will default the cache back to false.

Also, I would suggest putting your alert inside of the onOpen event handler in addition to the success handler just to be sure that's also being called. So that may help you debug a bit further.